# Substring set of string between given characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, substring

String I get is

```
["2021-01-13T09:45:48.046Z","2021-01-14T09:45:48.096Z","2021-01-15T09:45:48.099Z"]
```

Here I want to delete substring from T to Z  for converting to this form:

```
["2021-01-13","2021-01-14","2021-01-15"]
```

I did like that but it replaces only the first string and deletes others, How can I do this separately for each

```
notFound=notFound.replace(/\T.*\Z/g, '');
```

Can I do this with the javascript substring function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you said String so you will have to parse it.

```js
const str = '["2021-01-13T09:45:48.046Z","2021-01-14T09:45:48.096Z","2021-01-15T09:45:48.099Z"]';

let x = JSON.parse(str).map((e) => e.replace(/\T.*\Z/g,  ''));

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could replace with an nongready search.

```js
const
    data = '["2021-01-13T09:45:48.046Z","2021-01-14T09:45:48.096Z","2021-01-15T09:45:48.099Z"]',
    result = data.replace(/T.*?Z/g, '');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got it right, just do a loop like this:

```
["2021-01-13T09:45:48.046Z","2021-01-14T09:45:48.096Z","2021-01-15T09:45:48.099Z"].map(s => s.replace(/\T.*\Z/g, ''));
```

Comment: Um I did read the question and my answer fits good.

Comment: what do you get from the opening line "String I get is"? There is a string-encoded array - not an array

Comment: Sometimes comments can be misleading I like to read the code and try fix the problem. What I get from that line is that the author has some sort of string but it's not a string it's an array of strings. So I apply `.map` to the array and return the substring. What is unclear here?

Comment: There is no mention of "array" in the post at all (but string). you shouldn't assume things. see the tags even

Comment: Well if the author actually means string then the code should look something like this:

    `'["2021-01-13T09:45:48.046Z","2021-01-14T09:45:48.096Z","2021-01-15T09:45:48.099Z"]'`

instead of what's written.

Answer (score 1):

**I think you mean you have an *array* initially, rather than a string, in which case, this answer should suffice.**

You can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do the replacement on each element of the array.

```js
const x = ["2021-01-13T09:45:48.046Z", "2021-01-14T09:45:48.096Z", "2021-01-15T09:45:48.099Z"];
const y = x.map(e => {
  return e.replace(/T.*Z/, "");
});
console.log(y);
```

Side note: you don't need to escape the `T` and `Z` in the regular expression, and the global flag is redundant.

Comment: I suspect the OP meant to say *array* rather than *string* (which is likely IMO). Perhaps the OP can clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are always in the same format, you could turn the string into an array and then also split on `T` and take the first part.

```js
const str = '["2021-01-13T09:45:48.046Z","2021-01-14T09:45:48.096Z","2021-01-15T09:45:48.099Z"]';
let result = JSON.parse(str).map(s => s.split("T")[0]);
console.log(result);
```

For a specific match, you could use a pattern to match the datetime like format `^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T)\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z$` and replace with capturing group 1.

```js
const str = '["2021-01-13T09:45:48.046Z","2021-01-14T09:45:48.096Z","2021-01-15T09:45:48.099Z"]';
let result = JSON.parse(str).map(s =>
  s.replace(/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z$/, "$1")
);
console.log(result);
```